# ServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate") returns null

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate, apache-tomee

I've got a stop-ship problem that is driving me crazy. I hope that one of you experts out there can help.

I'm running the latest release version of TomEE+ (1.6.0.2) and the latest version of Java 8 (build 1.8.0_05-b13). No matter what I try, the following line of code in my HttpServlet always returns null.

```
X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

I initially assumed that I had specified the attribute name incorrectly, so to diagnose the problem, I decided to take a look at the full list of attributes using the following:

```
Enumeration<String> enums = request.getAttributeNames();
```

However that showed me were only two attributes: one for the cipher suite and the other for the key strength.

I read the other articles and verified that my connector was correct and that it had the clientAuth attribute set properly. Here's the connector:

```
<Connector port="4449" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
           SSLCertificateFile="/etc/unipagos/certs/pay.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/etc/unipagos/certs/pay.key"
           SSLVerifyClient="required"
           SSLHonorCipherOrder="true"
           ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"/>
```

The connection seems to work, however using `openssl s_client` with `-msg` shows that the server isn't asking for the client certificate.

Why is the server not asking for a client certificate? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to set `SSLCACertificateFile` or `SSLCACertificatePath`? You'd normally want them when using client-certificate authentication.

Comment: Let me try those and see if that works.

Comment: Okay, a question...I'm doing direct TLS/SSL in Tomcat/TomEE and not using Apache or mod_ssl. Given that, do these two options still apply?

Comment: Yes, you're using the APR protocol (`Http11AprProtocol`), so you should refer to the APR section of the manual, which is very close to the `mod_ssl` options (it even links to it).

Comment: I added the `SSLCACertificateFile` attribute, pointing it to a two-deep certificate chain, and it had no effect. :( Any ideas?

Comment: You generally don't need a chain there, just a bunch of CA certificates you're willing to accept (you can have intermediate certs, though, if you wish). It might be worth trying without APR, with the Java connectors directly (you'll need to convert your key+cert into a keystore, `PKCS12` might be the easiest).

Comment: I am looking for same answer. @Paul did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a working connector configuration for tomee and server is requesting client cert.
you can try

```
<Connector port="7443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
                SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"
                SSLVerifyClient="require"
                SSLCertificateFile="/opt/_cdrom_apache/certs/ec-dev-apr.pem"
                SSLCertificateKeyFile="/opt/_cdrom_apache/certs/ec-dev.key"
                SSLCACertificateFile="/opt/_cdrom_apache/certs/CA.pem"
               />
```